# Can a Steam card in USD currency be redeemed in PHP currency?

Tags: steam

I have a Steam card but it is in USD currency. I am in the Philippines so my account is in PHP currency. I can't redeem the said card because the currency is not the same.

1. How can I redeem said card?
2. Is it possible to redeem the card in my current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You can't.

[You used to be able to do it](https://web.archive.org/web/20180728193820/https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1122-RTSC-0478), [but due to fraud and currency exchange reasons](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1122-RTSC-0478), gift cards, like Apple/Google Play, are also region locked.

Instead, you are now encouraged to buy [Digital Giftcards](https://store.steampowered.com/digitalgiftcards/), which automatically convert currencies.

[image]

[image]

NB: It was just coincidental that exchange rates were 1:1.

Comment: i see thank you